# Generate Tailwind CSS in the browser

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I have web app that allows users to enter their own HTML templates in Liquid, like a website builder. I'd like to allow my users to use [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) in their custom templates, and then I would generate and save a compiled per-user CSS file based on the classes used in their custom template.

I understand I could do this using the Tailwind [standalone executable](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli) on my server. But rather than have to manage a binary, I'd rather it just run in the browser since users create/edit their templates very rarely, and I'd persist the generated CSS. I'm also not generally using Tailwind in this app, I just want my users to be able to use it in their templates.

So basically, I'm wondering what the simplest way to use Tailwind in a JavaScript function where I can pass it some HTML and it will return generated CSS. Basically just what https://play.tailwindcss.com/ ([source here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/play.tailwindcss.com)) does with the "Generated CSS" pane.

Basically I'm looking for something like:

```html
<script src="tailwindcss.js"></script>
<script>
  const inputHtml = '<div class="relative"></div>'; // example
  const outputCss = SOMETHING(inputHtml);
  console.log(outputCss) // this example would spit out: .relative { position: relative; }
</script>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either use the binary, or create a compiled CSS file that has *everything* included.

To use the binary you could create a back-end endpoint that you pass a template and tailwind config to, have it generate the minified CSS and return that CSS to the front-end.

Since it returns the CSS to the front-end you can then have the front-end save it along with the template and reference it as needed.

Keeping this as a stand-alone endpoint makes it much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tailwind like this when building your templates:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn

Then you can get the "compiled" CSS from style tags generated by the script, save it and use that for actual webpages deployed with the template.

Please note:

> The Play CDN is designed for development purposes only, and is not the best choice for production.

They don't recommend it for production because it's slow to build styles dynamically after user loads the page, but using this for building templates is different, since you need to do it dynamically anyway and slow CSS loading time inside the template editor doesn't really matter. I'd just make sure to use the "compiled" CSS on actual end user websites.

This solution is easier to maintain and probably faster than a binary on a server.

- No network requests needed = probably faster
- No need to update anything when new tailwind version comes out.
- No server maintenance. If your tailwind binary server goes down your users cannot use the service. If tailwind CDN goes down users can still use it since the script its cached on their browser. This works offline.

Comment: This is not good to production application.

Comment: @KannuMandora yes, I did mention that in a quote from tailwind docs for anyone else coming here. Did you read that?

For this question it's completely valid, since it's used to build templates, and not to build CSS for end users.

Care to elaborate why you think it is not good for building templates where CSS loading time is the least of your concerns?